# Unbounded polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $d$ on $R^n$, and let $\tilde{p}(x)$ be the homogeneous components with degree $d$, then how do we prove that:

if $\tilde{p}(x)$ is unbounded below, then $p(x)$ is unbounded below.

The statement is easy to understand. Because the components of the highest degree has a larger changing rate, so if $\tilde{p}(x)$ is unbounded below, there is no way that $p(x)$ is bounded below, but how to write a more formal proof of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$\overline{p}$ is a homogeneous (of degree $d$) function, so the only way it can be unbounded below is if there is a point on the unit sphere where it is negative. Call that direction $u$ Then $\overline{p}(t u) = C t^d,$ where $C<0.$ On the other hand, $(p-\overline{p}) (t u) = o(t^d),$ so you are golden (that is basically the argument you give, of course).